# How to find memory size on Windows 7 64 bit using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying following command, but it does not display the size:

`Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory`

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gwmi win32_computersystem | select totalphysicalmemory
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to read would be:

```
 [Math]::Round(((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select -Expand  TotalPhysicalMemory)/ 1GB),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

$WMI_ComputerSystem = Get-WmiObject -computername $Current_System.Computer_Name -class Win32_computersystem
$WMI_ComputerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory

Is not accurate.

$WMI_PM = Get-WmiObject -computername $Current_System.Computer_Name -class Win32_physicalmemory

Returns the size of each DIMM. You can parse through each of the returned values and add them up for an accurate value.